# Narrow component prop to values of other prop (Vue composition API + Typescript>

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I one of my components I'm using an interface to define the props, which defines options for a menu and offers the possibility to set a default selection. The default selection however currently can be any string. I would like it to only be possible to pass in one of the previously defined `options[?].value`.

#### MyComponent.vue

```js
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
interface MenuOptions {
  options: Array<{
    label: string,
    value: string
  }>,
  defaultSelection?: string
}

const props = defineProps<MenuOptions>();
</script>
```

#### OtherComponent.vue

```js
<template>
  <MyComponent
    :options= [
      { label: 'Foo', value: 'foo' }
      { label: 'Bar', value: 'bar' }
    ]
    default-selection="bar"
  ></MyComponent>
</template>
```

Currently, the approach is to do a runtime check inside `MyComponent` and simply don't set a default if the value doesn't match one of the provided values for the options. But I'd like typescript to already warn in advance, that the default value is invalid.

Is this even possible? If not, are there better ways to set this up?